# Add value to array in stylus lang css

Tags: css, stylus

I have 2 arrays. In another expression, in another mediaquery, how do I pull values ​​from one array and insert them into another?

have no idia, im try everything helps pls

```
breakpointes = {d-lg: 1600, d-md: 1300, d-sm: 1050, t-md: 900, t-md: 800, t-sm: 700, m-lg: 600, m-md: 500, m-sm: 399}

mq = {}

for index, key in breakpointes
    push(mq, index: '(max-width '+key+'px)')

@media mq[d-lg]
  .vlock
    display block
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mq = {}
for index, key in breakpointes 
    push(mq, mq[index] = '(max-width '+key+'px)')
```